# Insert all and validate duplicates in Oracle from DataFactory

Tags: oracle, azure-data-factory

I must execute multiple insert from azure data factory to Oracle and I am using the following statement

```
INSERT ALL INTO TABLENAME (CTCPIA,CTAN01,CTAN02,CTCRCD,CTCRR,CTAAN05,CTAAN04,CTCRCA,CTCRRB,CTDL011,CTDSG,CTCSIC,CTCPIL,CTEDDJ,CTUSER,CTPID,CTMKEY,CTUPMJ,CTTDAY) SELECT 'XXXX','31028775300.00','31028775300.00','COP','1','0.00','0.00','COP','0.00','Published','Executing','XXXX','XXXX','123059','LAKE-CHEC','XXX','XXX','122097','165729' FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLENAME WHERE CTCPIA='XXXX') SELECT * FROM dual;
```

I am adding the lines WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLENAME WHERE CTCPIA='XXXX') to validate that no duplicates are inserted, however from datafactory it is throwing me the following error

[image]

How could I validate duplicates within the INSERT ALL statement? since I have to execute a lot of INSERT statements.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where should be after the select.

Comment: e.g. insert all into test (id,name) select 1,'adsa' from dual where exists (select 1 from dual)

Comment: I tried the way you put the example, but the same error "SQL command not properly ended" comes out

Comment: Can you please update question with what you tried, so it can be checked/tested

Comment: This is the code I tried from datafactory:  INSERT ALL 
INTO TABLENAME  (CTCPIA,CTAN01,CTAN02,CTCRCD,CTCRR,CTAAN05,CTAAN04,CTCRCA,CTCRRB,CTDL011,CTDSG,CTCSIC,CTCPIL,CTEDDJ,CTUSER,CTPID,CTMKEY,CTUPMJ,CTTDAY) 
SELECT 'XXXX','31028775300.00','31028775300.00','COP','1','0.00','0.00','COP','0.00','Published','Executing','XXXX','XXXX','123059','XXXX','XXXX','XXXX','122097','165729' FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLENAME  WHERE CTCPIA='XXXX') SELECT * FROM dual;

Comment: If I try it in the following way, it works fine inside the INSERT ALL, but I can't do the required validation: INSERT ALL 

INTO TABLENAME CTCPIA,CTAN01,CTAN02,CTCRCD,CTCRR,CTAAN05,CTAAN04,CTCRCA,CTCRRB,CTDL011,CTDSG,CTCSIC,CTCPIL,CTEDDJ,CTUSER,CTPID,CTMKEY,CTUPMJ,CTTDAY) 
VALUE('XXXX','31028775300.00','31028775300.00','COP','1','0.00','0.00','COP','0.00','Published','Executing','XXXX','XXXX','123059','XXXX','XXXX','XXXX','122097','165729')

SELECT * FROM dual;

Comment: You cannot specify another select as part of where clause that is not correct syntax.

Comment: so how can I validate that the record does not exist within an INSERT ALL statement

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to refer [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) for INSERT ALL (Section: "The multitable insert statement looks like this")

I performed an insert to explain the scenario, see if that matches your use-case.

Current state of a table -

```
select * from test;

   ID NAME
----- ----------
    1 adsa
    2 fa
    2 xxx
```

Inserting 'ALL' to table TEST to avoid duplicates
based on condition (value NOT EXISTS)- No rows are inserted.

```
insert all
into test (id, name)
values (id+1, name||'a')
into test (id, name)
values (id+2, name||'b')
into test (id, name)
values (id+3, name||'c')
select 1 as id,'any name' as name from dual
where NOT EXISTS
(select 1 from test where name='xxx');

0 rows created.
```

Inserting 'ALL' to table TEST
based on condition (value EXISTS)-

```
insert all
into test (id, name)
values (id+1, name||'a')
into test (id, name)
values (id+2, name||'b')
into test (id, name)
values (id+3, name||'c')
select 1 as id,'any name' as name from dual
where EXISTS
(select 1 from test where name='xxx');

3 rows created.

select * from test;

   ID NAME
----- ----------
    1 adsa
    2 fa
    2 xxx
    2 any namea
    3 any nameb
    4 any namec
```